Jest test kept failing so I decided to debug by using console.log(lowerCaseRegex.test(string)); but then the test passed because of that console.log?
I have the following custom hook which has a function that takes a string which might contain an interpolation which requires me to lower case the string inside of it, like this:
Hello, I am {{#lowerCase}}Lower Case{{/lowerCase}}

should become
Hello, I am lower case

Now this works fine, however, as I started testing the hook, the results were a bit weird. My hook looks like this:
import { useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';

const useIntepolatedMessage = () => {
    const lowerCaseRegex = useMemo(() => /{{#lowerCase}}(.*?){{\/lowerCase}}/g, []);

    const lowerCaseInterpolation = useCallback(
        (inputString: string) => {
            const result = inputString.replace(lowerCaseRegex, (match, group) => group.toLowerCase());

            return result;
        },
        [lowerCaseRegex]
    );

    const interpolatedMessage = useCallback(
        (string: string) => {
            if (!lowerCaseRegex.test(string)) return string;

            if (lowerCaseRegex.test(string)) {
                string = lowerCaseInterpolation(string);
            }

            return string;
        },
        [activityContentRegex, controller?.steps, lowerCaseInterpolation, lowerCaseRegex, userActivityContent]
    );

    return { interpolatedMessage };
};

export default useIntepolatedMessage;

The weird issue is that my test is failing until I console.log(lowerCaseRegex.test(string)); right before the:
            if (lowerCaseRegex.test(string)) {
                string = lowerCaseInterpolation(string);
            }

If that console.log(lowerCaseRegex.test(string)); is present, the string gets interpolated even though console.log(lowerCaseRegex.test(string)); evaluates to false.
Is there something wrong with my code?

Global regex is stateful, so calling myregex.test(mystring) where myregex has a g flag - will possibly give  different results when it is called more than once.

See: Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?

In this case, you might just find it easier to remove the .test() calls. What's the benefit of testing before you do your .replace() call here? If your string doesn't match the regex then nothing will be replaced, so you can just call .replace() without doing a test and you'll get the string output.
